# error(function) on img element causing infinite loop when the replacement image doesn't load

Tags: jquery, image

My script appends to a table some code to load images. However, it interprets the image link from the contents of the table. This sometimes causes it to load errornouse images. I created a placeholder image that loads if the first image fails, however if this placeholder fails to load, then the script goes into an infinite loop.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('tr[id^="mini"]').each(function(index) {
        var s = $(this).find('td:first');
        var product = s.text().replace(/\s+/g, '');
        s.append('<br><a href="/-p/' + product + '.htm" target="_blank">View Live</a><br><a title="Click for bigger image" href="/PhotoDetails.asp?ShowDESC=Y\&amp;ProductCode=' + product + '" onclick="window.open(\'/PhotoDetails.asp?ShowDESC=Y\&amp;ProductCode=' + product + '\',\'Option\',\'scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,status=no,location=no,width=600,height=640\'); return false;" target="_blank"><img src="/v/vspfiles/photos/' + product + '-0.jpg" border="0" style="max-width:150px;max-height:150px" id="monkey-inserted-image" /></a>');
    });
    // This checks for images that do not load //
    $('img#monkey-inserted-image').error(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr("id").attr("src", "/tamper/noimage1.png");
        // If this image fails to load, an infinite loop is created //
    });
});
```

I tried using .removeAttr() hoping that this would stop the loop, but it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why wouldn't you expect this? You are basically telling it to try again each time it fails, so obviously if the `src` is bad then it will fail each time.

The `removeAttr()` will not do what you think it does. The `error` event is already registered, if you are trying to un-register it then you need to do it a different way.

Perhaps like so:

```
$(this).unbind('error');
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to [unregister the `error` handler](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) when setting your placeholder:

```
$('img#monkey-inserted-image').error(function() {
    $(this).unbind("error").attr("src", "/tamper/noimage1.png");
    // No more infinite loop :-)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When handling the error, you should unbind that event so that it will not fire infinitely if the replacement image does not load

```
$('img#monkey-inserted-image').on('error', function() {
        $(this).off('error').attr("src", "/tamper/noimage1.png");
        // If this image fails to load, an infinite loop is created //
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop is "normal". You are listening to the error event on your image, so if your default placeholder image trigger an error, your function is called and you try again to put that placeholder image so the error event is triggered and you try again to put the placeholder ... well, i think you get it.

You can check the `src` attribute of your image. And if you are already handling a placeholder image, just do nothing (or a fallback).

```
$('img#monkey-inserted-image').error(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('src') == '/tamper/noimage1.png')) {
        // Do your fallback here
        return;
    }

    $(this).removeAttr("id").attr("src", "/tamper/noimage1.png");
    // If this image fails to load, an infinite loop is created //
});
```